# How do I write a jquery function that accepts a callback

Tags: jquery

i wrote a custom jquery function that accept a callback but not being able to understand how call back function will execute at the calling environment when animate function execution end.

here is my custom function code

```
jQuery.fn.busyToggle = function (flag, marginBottom, opacity, speed, easing, callback) {
        if (flag == 1) {
            return this.stop(true).animate({ marginBottom: marginBottom, opacity: opacity }, { queue: false, duration: speed });
        }
        else {
            return this.stop(true).animate({ marginBottom: marginBottom, opacity: opacity }, { queue: false, duration: speed });
        }
    };
```

this way i am calling this function

```
$('#BusyBox').busyToggle(flag,0,1,500);
```

i need to know that how to capture when animate function end from calling environment. if possible please discuss in detail. thanks

Comment: [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) accepts a callback as argument. Just pass `callback` to it. Have a look at the examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your callback to the complete option of `animate`

```
jQuery.fn.busyToggle = function (flag, marginBottom, opacity, speed, easing, callback) {
    ...
    this.stop(true).animate({ marginBottom: marginBottom, opacity: opacity }, { queue: false, duration: speed, complete: callback });
};

$('#BusyBox').busyToggle(flag,0,1,500, function(){ 
    // do something on complete
});
```

Comment: u did not say how to attach callback function when i will call busyToggle().....can i call like this $('#BusyBox').busyToggle(flag,0,1,500,function(){alert('complete...')});

Comment: there could be any problem because i am not passing any value for easing argument ? please discuss in detail...thanks

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, you pass the callback exactly how you do it with other jQuery methods. Functions are just values in JavaScript, links strings and numbers and you can treat them the same way.

Comment: @Thomas added it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the callback function provided by `.animate()`
Another way is to add it to the chain queue like:

```
jQuery.fn.busyToggle = function(flag, marginBottom, opacity, speed, easing, callback) {
    if (flag == 1) {
        return this.stop(true).animate({
            marginBottom: marginBottom,
            opacity: opacity
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: speed
        }).queue(callback);
    }
    else {
        return this.stop(true).animate({
            marginBottom: marginBottom,
            opacity: opacity
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: speed
        }).queue(callback);
    }
};​
```

Comment: u did not say how to attach callback function when i will call busyToggle().....can i call like this $('#BusyBox').busyToggle(flag,0,1,500,function(){alert('complete...')});